# Is there an equation to find the next power-of-two sequence in this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Along the lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951360/partition-n-where-the-count-of-parts-and-each-part-are-a-power-of-2-and-part-si), say we are are counting, and every time we increment by 1, we end up with a slightly modified sequence that (1) has a power-of-two length, and (2) each element in the sequence is a power of two UP TO MAX value of 32.

So we go like this:

```
[1]                     // 1
[2]                     // 2
[2, 1]                  // 3
[4]                     // 4
[4, 1]                  // 5
[4, 2]                  // 6
[4, 1, 1, 1]            // 7
[8]                     // 8
...
```

The question is, is there an equation to find the next item in the sequence, such that you wouldn't have to recompute it from scratch each time? Is there no way to take an existing sequence (or "pattern") and slightly modify it to increment the "summed" value by 1? For example, a larger number might look like this in array form (remembering 32 is the max size for this example):

```
  [32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32,
   32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 16, 4]
```

That is acceptable because every number is a power of two, and there are 16 (power of two) items. But now we add one. The next value might be this, which sums to 1 more, but is also fitting the power-of-two paradigm:

```
  [32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32,
   32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32,  4,  1, 
    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 
    1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]
```

Basically, is there an equation for finding the next element in this sequence?

Or is this impossible, and the only way to do it is to programmatically compute the sequence from scratch each time?

Comment: Why don't you have [8] instead of [4, 4] for 8?

Comment: You could pick either, whatever works to solve the problem in any way. Updated.

Comment: For $2^n$ take $2^n$ ones, and for $2^n+t$ take $t$ twos and $2^n-t$ ones where $t<2^n$.

Comment: @kingW3 interesting! That is kind of cheating haha. Can it be possible to maximize the digits as in the example instead? Having the largest possible digits at the beginning?